# Accessing data from JSON field in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I am working with a database which is using json as a data type in a Postgres DB and am having issues trying to extract values from the json document. I've done some researching around and have tried a variety of solutions including using

- `json_array_elements`
- `response ->> 'filterEntryId'`
- `json_populate_recordset(null::obj, table.column -> 'filterEntryId'`

but have not been successful. I am starting to think that it is the way that the json is being stored in the column, ie that it starts with a '[' instead of a '{'.

Below is an example of the value of the json field.

```
 [{
    "filterEntryId":373,
    "length":3,
    "locale":"en",
    "matched":"dog",
    "quality":1.0,
    "root":"dog",
    "severity":"mild",
    "start":2,
    "tags":["Vulgarity"],
    "type":"blacklist"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. I was mis-using the `json_array_elements` function.

In the event that anyone stumbles across this, here is the correct way to query the json

```
select
    json_array_elements(column) ->> 'filterEntryId'
from table
```

Essentially you are first accessing the document and then grabbing what you need from it. I think this had to be done this way due to the '[' around the data in the column.

Feel free, anyone, to expand on my explanation.